# Show a google map in an appwidget?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-appwidget

I'd like to show a google map in my appwidget, but don't know how to do this. Is there anyone that knows how one can proceed with this?

Do I have to convert a view to a bitmap or does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a live Google map, you cannot. In http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout you can find the list of supported views in appwidgets. MapView is not there unfortunately. If your map can be just an static image, you could convert it to a bitmap and include it in an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

To show a map on a widget you can use static maps api and an imageView https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/